# test result: Error. Program `sh' timed out (timeout set to 480000ms, elapsed time including timeout handling was 480002ms)

Tags: java, testing, java-8, timeout

When performing regression testing on OpenJDK, the error "--Fail: waitForJdbMsg timed out after 40 seconds, looking for /]/, in 1 lines; exitting" occurred when testing a shell script with jdi-based debugging function through JTreg, and A timeout occurs, ultimately causing the test case to fail.

DeoptimizeWalk.sh（shell test script）：

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# Copyright (c) 2002, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
# DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT NOTICES OR THIS FILE HEADER.
#
# This code is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 only, as
# published by the Free Software Foundation.
#
# This code is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
# ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License
# version 2 for more details (a copy is included in the LICENSE file that
# accompanied this code).
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License version
# 2 along with this work; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
# Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA.
#
# Please contact Oracle, 500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA 94065 USA
# or visit www.oracle.com if you need additional information or have any
# questions.
#

#  @test
#  @bug 4525714
#  @summary jtreg test PopAsynchronousTest fails in build 85 with -Xcomp
#  @author Jim Holmlund/Swamy Venkataramanappa
#  @run shell DeoptimizeWalk.sh

#  This is another test of the same bug.  The bug occurs when trying
#  to walk the stack of a deoptimized thread.  We can do this
#  by running in -Xcomp mode and by doing a step which causes deopt,
#  and then a 'where'.  This will cause not all the frames to be shown.

compileOptions=-g

echo "*********** This test only fails with -Xcomp ***************"
createJavaFile()
{
    cat <<EOF > $1.java.1

public class $1 {
    static public void main(String[] args) {
       $1 mine = new $1();
       mine.a1(89);
    }

    public void a1(int p1) {
      int v1 = 89;
      System.out.println("a1" + v1);
      a2(89);
    }


    public void a2(int pp) {
      int v2 = 89;
      System.out.println("a2" + v2);
      a3(89);
    }

    public void a3(int pp) {
      int v3 = 89;
      System.out.println("a3");  //@ 1 breakpoint
      a4(22);                  // it passes if this line is commented out
      System.out.println("jj");
    }
    
    public void a4(int pp) {
      int v4 = 90;
      System.out.println("a4: @1 breakpoint here");
    }
}
EOF
}

# This is called to feed cmds to jdb.
dojdbCmds()
{
    setBkpts @1
    runToBkpt @1
    cmd where
    #cmd next
    cmd step
    cmd where
    cmd quit
    jdbFailIfNotPresent "shtest\.main" 3
}


mysetup()
{
    if [ -z "$TESTSRC" ] ; then
        TESTSRC=.
    fi

    for ii in . $TESTSRC $TESTSRC/.. ; do
        if [ -r "$ii/ShellScaffold.sh" ] ; then
            . $ii/ShellScaffold.sh 
            break
        fi
    done
}

# You could replace this next line with the contents
# of ShellScaffold.sh and this script will run just the same.
mysetup

runit
debuggeeFailIfPresent "Internal exception:"
pass
```

jtr file of jtreg：

```
#Test Results (version 2)
#Mon Mar 25 18:22:47 CST 2024
#-----testdescription-----
$file=/path/to/kunzejdk/PrimetonKunZe-8/jdk/test/com/sun/jdi/DeoptimizeWalk.sh
$root=/path/to/kunzejdk/PrimetonKunZe-8/jdk/test
author=Jim Holmlund/Swamy Venkataramanappa
keywords=bug4525714 shell
run=USER_SPECIFIED shell DeoptimizeWalk.sh\n
source=DeoptimizeWalk.sh
title=jtreg test PopAsynchronousTest fails in build 85 with -Xcomp

#-----environment-----

#-----testresult-----
description=file\:/path/to/kunzejdk/PrimetonKunZe-8/jdk/test/com/sun/jdi/DeoptimizeWalk.sh
elapsed=480003 0\:08\:00.003
end=Mon Mar 25 18\:22\:47 CST 2024
environment=regtest
execStatus=Error. Program `sh' timed out (timeout set to 480000ms, elapsed time including timeout handling was 480002ms).
harnessLoaderMode=Classpath Loader
harnessVariety=Full Bundle
hostname=kylin-124
javatestOS=Linux 4.19.90-52.22.v2207.ky10.x86_64 (amd64)
javatestVersion=6.0-ea+b04-2024-03-25
jtregVersion=jtreg jtreg6 dev jtreg6
script=com.sun.javatest.regtest.exec.RegressionScript
sections=script_messages shell
start=Mon Mar 25 18\:14\:47 CST 2024
test=com/sun/jdi/DeoptimizeWalk.sh
testJDK=/path/to/kunzejdk/PrimetonKunZe-8/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/images/j2sdk-image
totalTime=480004
user.name=root
work=/path/to/kunzejdk/PrimetonKunZe-8/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/testoutput/jdk_tier1/JTwork/com/sun/jdi

#section:script_messages
----------messages:(4/255)----------
JDK under test: /path/to/kunzejdk/PrimetonKunZe-8/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/images/j2sdk-image
openjdk version "1.8.0_402"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Kunze (build 1.8.0_402-12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Kunze (build 25.402-b12, mixed mode)

#section:shell
----------messages:(3/125)----------
command: shell DeoptimizeWalk.sh
reason: User specified action: run shell DeoptimizeWalk.sh 
elapsed time (seconds): 480.003
----------System.out:(7/370)*----------
*********** This test only fails with -Xcomp ***************
--Compiling first version of /path/to/kunzejdk/PrimetonKunZe-8/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/testoutput/jdk_tier1/JTwork/classes/0/com/sun/jdi/aa850509/shtest.java with options: -g
compiling  shtest.java

--Starting jdb, address=
\u76d1\u542c\u5730\u5740: kylin-124:45527
Timeout refired 480 times
----------System.err:(87/5033)*----------
ShellScaffold.sh: Version
vv jdbOutFile  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
\u76d1\u542c\u5730\u5740: kylin-124:45527
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
-- jdb process info ----------------------
      850604 TTY -Dapplication.home=/path/to/kunzejdk/PrimetonKunZe-8/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/images/j2sdk-image -Xms8m -DHANGINGJAVA-850509_JDB
-- jdb threads: jstack 850604
2024-03-25 18:15:31
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.402-b12 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=0.44ms elapsed=0.20s tid=0x00007f5860001000 nid=0xd086a waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=0.04ms elapsed=43.15s tid=0x00007f58e40e1800 nid=0xcfad0 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread3" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=35.19ms elapsed=43.15s tid=0x00007f58e40de800 nid=0xcfacf waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread2" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=3.45ms elapsed=43.16s tid=0x00007f58e40dc800 nid=0xcface waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=3.85ms elapsed=43.16s tid=0x00007f58e40db000 nid=0xcfacd waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=4.98ms elapsed=43.16s tid=0x00007f58e40d8000 nid=0xcfacc waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=0.35ms elapsed=43.16s tid=0x00007f58e40d5000 nid=0xcfacb runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 cpu=0.36ms elapsed=43.18s tid=0x00007f58e40a2000 nid=0xcfaca in Object.wait() [0x00007f5889b69000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000749481280> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
    - locked <0x0000000749481280> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:165)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:188)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 cpu=0.57ms elapsed=43.18s tid=0x00007f58e409d800 nid=0xcfac9 in Object.wait() [0x00007f5889c6a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000749481448> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x0000000749481448> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=120.81ms elapsed=43.20s tid=0x00007f58e400b800 nid=0xcfab2 runnable [0x00007f58ea2eb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:560)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:528)
    at com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketTransportService.accept(SocketTransportService.java:348)
    at com.sun.tools.jdi.GenericListeningConnector.accept(GenericListeningConnector.java:151)
    at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.VMConnection.listenTarget(VMConnection.java:536)
    at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.VMConnection.open(VMConnection.java:330)
    - locked <0x00000007493a60d8> (a com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.VMConnection)
    at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.Env.init(Env.java:63)
    at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.TTY.main(TTY.java:1083)

"VM Thread" os_prio=0 cpu=2.52ms elapsed=43.18s tid=0x00007f58e4095800 nid=0xcfac7 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 cpu=1.57ms elapsed=43.20s tid=0x00007f58e4021000 nid=0xcfab6 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 cpu=0.99ms elapsed=43.20s tid=0x00007f58e4023000 nid=0xcfab7 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 cpu=0.88ms elapsed=43.20s tid=0x00007f58e4025000 nid=0xcfab8 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 cpu=0.08ms elapsed=43.20s tid=0x00007f58e4026800 nid=0xcfab9 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 cpu=0.05ms elapsed=43.20s tid=0x00007f58e4028800 nid=0xcfaba runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 cpu=0.06ms elapsed=43.20s tid=0x00007f58e402a000 nid=0xcfabb runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 cpu=0.05ms elapsed=43.20s tid=0x00007f58e402c000 nid=0xcfabc runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 cpu=0.08ms elapsed=43.20s tid=0x00007f58e402d800 nid=0xcfabd runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 cpu=17.44ms elapsed=43.15s tid=0x00007f58e40e4000 nid=0xcfad1 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 12

------------------------------------------

----------rerun:(21/1139)*----------
cd /path/to/kunzejdk/PrimetonKunZe-8/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/testoutput/jdk_tier1/JTwork/scratch/2 && \\
HOME=/root \\
LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8 \\
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin \\
TESTSRC=/path/to/kunzejdk/PrimetonKunZe-8/jdk/test/com/sun/jdi \\
TESTSRCPATH=/path/to/kunzejdk/PrimetonKunZe-8/jdk/test/com/sun/jdi \\
TESTCLASSES=/path/to/kunzejdk/PrimetonKunZe-8/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/testoutput/jdk_tier1/JTwork/classes/0/com/sun/jdi \\
TESTCLASSPATH=/path/to/kunzejdk/PrimetonKunZe-8/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/testoutput/jdk_tier1/JTwork/classes/0/com/sun/jdi \\
COMPILEJAVA=/path/to/kunzejdk/PrimetonKunZe-8/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/images/j2sdk-image \\
TESTJAVA=/path/to/kunzejdk/PrimetonKunZe-8/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/images/j2sdk-image \\
TESTVMOPTS='-ea -esa -Xmx512m' \\
TESTTOOLVMOPTS='-J-ea -J-esa -J-Xmx512m' \\
TESTJAVACOPTS= \\
TESTJAVAOPTS= \\
TESTTIMEOUTFACTOR=4.0 \\
TESTROOT=/path/to/kunzejdk/PrimetonKunZe-8/jdk/test \\
FS=/ \\
PS=: \\
NULL=/dev/null \\
    sh \\
        /path/to/kunzejdk/PrimetonKunZe-8/jdk/test/com/sun/jdi/DeoptimizeWalk.sh
result: Error. Program `sh' timed out (timeout set to 480000ms, elapsed time including timeout handling was 480002ms).


test result: Error. Program `sh' timed out (timeout set to 480000ms, elapsed time including timeout handling was 480002ms).
```

test result:

```
test result: Error. Program `sh' timed out (timeout set to 480000ms, elapsed time including timeout handling was 480002ms).
```

The problem has been solved. It was caused by the local language environment of the operating system. Set the local language environment to en_US.UTF-8 and it will be fine.

- Check locale
  `echo $LANG`
- Set locale
  `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. It was caused by the local language environment of the operating system. Set the local language environment to `en_US.UTF-8` and it will be fine.

- Check locale:

`echo $LANG`

- Set locale:

`export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`